# How to disable drag and drop event into the tinymce editor

Tags: drag-and-drop, tinymce

I want to disable drag and drop text and image into the tinymce Editor (textarea). I tried to search on the web and still cannot find the working answer. Can anyone please provide me the snippet that i can work around ? Thanks much.

Anyone ? :(

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible using the [paste](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste) plugin. The `paste_block_drop` option should do just what you want.